# I need help programming functions for my buttons (importing, exporting)

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a really **basic** software where the user can:

1) press a button to import a .csv file, and the program will read the file and print it

2) press another button to sort the data a specific way

3) Press a third and final button to export that data as a new .csv file

Basically, I need help on steps **1 and 3**, I have no clue how to do it.

MY CODE:

```
from tkinter import *

import tkinter

import tkinter.messagebox

top = Toplevel()


def UploadAction():
#Allows user to import a .csv of their choice into the program
#Python should read the file into the system and display the contents


def SortingCSV():
#Allows user to switch the contents of the file to the desired settings


def Export():
#Exports the manipulated data into a new .csv file and downloads it    


B=Button(top, text ="Upload", command = UploadAction).grid(row=2,column=1)

B=Button(top, text ="Convert File", command = SortingCSV).grid(row=6, column=1)

B=Button(top, text ="Download File", command = Export).grid(row=7,column=1)


top.mainloop()
```

Comment: what do you mean download it?Do u want to download it from web or the file is present in your pc and you want to print the contents on screen.What is type of data you want to sort.Give eg of your contents in csv file.

Comment: This is way too broad, and there are plenty of resources on the net that show you how to read and process csv files.

Comment: Sorry, I realize that my question was phrased weirdly. Basically I want to be able to open up a file dialog, and I'm having trouble with that.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of Python modules exist that simplify your life for this kind of problem.

There is one for working with csv : https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html

Good luck !